# installing zeromq under pypy

Tags: zeromq, pypy

I have installed zeromq under CPython. How can I install it that it runns also under pypy?

www.zeromq.org/

The problem is it that zeromq needs Cython.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To work with pypy, you need to use a ctypes-based binding, such as [pyzmq-ctypes](https://github.com/svpcom/pyzmq-ctypes) or [zmqpy](https://github.com/felipecruz/zmqpy).

**2013 Update:** pyzmq works with pypy now, so you can just `pip install pyzmq` on pypy.

Comment: Is anyone of them preferable? Especially speed wise?

Comment: I use neither, but I have heard people complain that pyzmq-ctypes is slow.  pyzmq-ctypes wraps libzmq directly, while zmqpy wraps czmq (a higher-level C binding to libzmq). It shouldn't be difficult to run a few simple benchmarks, though I know of no reports from anyone already having done that.

Comment: zmqpy as per its own web site is a work in progress, and the implementation is not as complete as pyzmq, e.g. zmq_setsockopt is implemented but not zmq_getsockopt, etc.

Comment: Hello! I'm the author of zmqpy. Nowdays, I would say that zmqpy is runs stable and it's pretty fast. It's not complete as PyZMQ but if you open an issue I'll try to close it as fast as I can.

Comment: Hi! Neither zmqpy or pyzmq-ctypes seem to be working with pypy (at least in my case, in 2014). Is there a zmq ctypes-based binding out there that's still being maintained?

Comment: zmqpy was merged into pyzmq as an alternate backend, so you can just use pyzmq with pypy now.